# The "Remove" button is not working

Tags: 7, forms, files

I'm using a "managed file" to upload an image, which works fine, but if you want to remove the image by clicking on the "Remove" button, nothing happens.

```
 $form['logo'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => 'Logo',
    '#default_value' => variable_get('logo', ''),
    '#theme' => 'mymodule_thumb_upload',
    '#upload_location' => 'public://my-files/',
    '#upload_validators' => array(
      'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
      'file_validate_size' => array(0.3*1024*1024),
      'file_validate_image_resolution'=>array('100x100'),
    ),
);
```

I'm using a custom theme, and I just realized when I switch back to 'Seven' the button works. But what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
function name_module_form() {
  $form['logo'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => 'Logo',
    '#default_value' => variable_get('logo', ''),
    '#description' => t('Upload File'),
    '#upload_validators' => array(
      'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
      'file_validate_size' => array(100 * 1024 * 1024),
    ),
    '#theme' => 'abc_thumb_upload',
    '#upload_location' => 'public://abc/',
    '#attributes' => array(
    'multiple' => 'multiple'
  ));
}

function name_module_theme() {
  return array(
    'abc_thumb_upload' => array(
    'render element' => 'element',
    'file' => 'name_module.module',
  ));
}

function theme_abc_thumb_upload($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  if (isset($element['#file']->uri)) {
    $output = '<div id="edit-logo-ajax-wrapper"><div class="form-item form-type-managed-file form-item-logo"><span class="file">';
    $output .= '<img height="100px" src="' . file_create_url($element['#file']->uri) . '" />';
    $output .= '</span><input type="submit" id="edit-' . isset($element['remove_button']['#name ']) . '-remove-button" name="' . isset($element['remove_button']['#name ']) . '_remove_button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-default form-submit ajax-processed">';
    $output .= '<input type="hidden" name="' . isset($element['remove_button']['#name ']) . '[fid]" value="' . $element['#file']->fid . '">';

    return $output;
  }
}
```